# How can i count registers from a table on laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i am trying to count the total of registers per type that exists on my table with Laravel, but i don´t know how to do it. I am new on Laravel.

I have 2 types on my table with an enum (Win and Lost) and wanna count how many of each do i have. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you explain your question in details? Do you want to get the count of win and count of lost from a table?

Comment: Yes, i want to display in a blade how many of each do i have example: Wins 10 Lost 7

Comment: what is you Model and column name?

Comment: Projects.php
projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Eloquent Model, You can simply count by column in your controller,

```
$winCount = YourModel::where('columnName','Win')->count();
$lostCount = YourModel::where('columnName','Lost')->count();
```

and pass these values to you view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **group by**.

```
select count(id), enum
from [yourTable]
group by enum
```

Or using Laravel Eloquent:

```
[YourModel]::select(DB::raw('count(id) as count'), 'enum'))->groupBy('enum')->get();
```

Comment: Not necessary to write raw queries here.

`$wins = Model::where('enum', 'win')->count();` and `$losts = Model::where('enum', 'lost')->count();`

Comment: This way you are doing 2 requests to database, while in my example you are doing everything in one call only. But of course if the app is small, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Sure @Denis. Your answer is the most efficient, but might me confusing for newbies.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with an Eloquent model, you can achieve this by doing:

Lets say your model is called **Registers**

```
use App\Registers;

$register = new Registers();
$wins = $register::where('type', 'Win')->count();

$lost = $register::where('type', 'Lost')->count();
```

In the above example, it is assumed your **ENUM** column is called **type**.

Comment: your answer should work but is not efficient. It can be solved on database side. The `all()` will load - as it says - all items on database, and all columns (since you didn't specified the columns to load) to the memory. In a table with many columns, or rows, it will be very slow and consume tons of memory. Instead, you can do a query and use the count aggregate, as suggested by @Muhaimenul Islam answer.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect your suggestion Elias Soares.